# Converting an algerberic expression into a function?

Tags: expression, algebra, javascript

I have been trying to create an expression to calculate brick and glass prices.

```
I'm working with a, b and c 

so the price is $30m^2  for bricks and $20m^2 for glass
```

A and B are walls C is a round window radius

```
A = 3m (not m^2) 
B = 2m (not m^2)
C = 1m (not m^2)
```

I believe that my expression **(a*b)*30 – (c^2*20)** works but how can I turn this into a java script function that in future I could use in a calculator to calculate prices etc...

Bit of a newbie with java script.

thanks all!

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking for. Is this `function cal(a,b,c) {return a*b*30 - Math.pow(c,2)*20;}`?

Comment: Your expression is incorrect -- you've left out a factor of π when calculating the area of the circle, and in any case the logic is wrong (the price of the glass is not subtracted from that of the bricks).

Comment: Also, if you set A or B to 0, both A and B's cost will evaluate as 0. Not sure if this is what you're expecting.

Comment: can you explain to me then how I would go about making an expression to calculate the price of bricks and glass combined? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following function `cost(a,b,c)` should do what you want, assuming I've understood the question:

```
function cost(a,b,c) { 
    return (a * b * 30) - (Math.PI * Math.pow(c,2) * 20) 
}
```

This returns `117.16814692820414` given the parameters `a = 3`, `b = 2` and `a = 1`.

An example of the `cost` function in use would be:

```
var price = cost(3,2,1);
```